# Single sanitization callback for multiple fields

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

hope everyone is doing good! How can I have a single sanitization callback for multiple fields?

Here is my code

```
add_action('admin_init','settings');


function settings(){
add_settings_section('menu_first_section',null,null,'plugin-menu');

add_settings_field('field_1','Field 1','field_1_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
register_setting('option_group_1','field_1',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_one','default'=> ''));

add_settings_field('field_2','Field 2','field_2_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
register_setting('option_group_2','field_2',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_two','default'=> ''));

}

function sanitize_one($input) {
  // validation

}

function sanitize_two($input) {
   // validation
}
```

How can I have a single sanitization callback for multiple fields and then access the values of it ($input)?

Comment: Just pass the same function name to `sanitize_callback` for both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I have a single sanitization callback for multiple fields and
> then access the values of it ($input)?

For fields with the same validation logic, just set `sanitize_callback` to the same callback, e.g. if `field_1` and `field_2` are single-line and text-only fields (i.e. no HTML allowed), you can use `'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'` for both fields. (see [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/))

But for custom callbacks which need to access the option name (maybe because the callback is shared among different field types), then:

### Option 1: Manually hook on `sanitize_option_<option name>`

[`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) uses the [`sanitize_option_<option name>` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/sanitize_option_option/) to register the sanitize callback, but the function calls [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) with the *fourth* parameter set to the default (i.e. `1`) and thus, only one parameter that will be passed to the sanitize callback, so it won't receive the option name (the `$option` parameter in the example below).

Therefore if you want to receive the option name, then do not set the `sanitize_callback` argument, and instead, manually hook on the above filter. E.g.

```php
// Shared sanitize callback:
// Just a basic example of validating based on the option/input name.
function sanitize_any( $value, $option ) {
    switch ( $option ) {
        case 'field_1':
            if ( empty( $value ) ) {
                add_settings_error( 'my_plugin_messages', 'missing_field_1',
                    'Please enter a valid value into Field 1.' );

                // Use the current database value. This will cancel saving the option.
                $value = get_option( $option );
            }

            break;

        // .. your code ...
    }

    return $value;
}

// Register the settings:
register_setting( 'option_group_1', 'field_1', array( 'default' => '' ) );
register_setting( 'option_group_2', 'field_2', array( 'default' => '' ) );

// Hook on sanitize_option_field_1 and sanitize_option_field_2:
add_filter( 'sanitize_option_field_1', 'sanitize_any', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'sanitize_option_field_2', 'sanitize_any', 10, 2 );

/* Sample <input>:
<input name="field_1" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'field_1' ) ); ?>">
*/
```

### Option 2: Use an array

If the inputs belong in the **same option group** (i.e. same form), you can store them in an array which means `field_1` and `field_2` would be in a single database option, e.g. one named `my_fields`. So for example:

```php
// This function returns the default values for my_fields.
function my_fields_default_options() {
    return array(
        'field_1' => '',
        'field_2' => '',
    );
}

// The sanitize callback:
function sanitize_my_fields( $value ) {
    $value = (array) $value;

    if ( empty( $value['field_1'] ) ) {
        add_settings_error( 'my_plugin_messages', 'missing_field_1',
            'Please enter a valid value into Field 1.' );

        // Use the current database value. This will cancel saving the option.
        $value = get_option( 'my_fields' );
    }

    // .. your code ...

    return $value;
}

// Register the setting:
register_setting( 'my_option_group', 'my_fields', array(
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_my_fields',
    'default'           => my_fields_default_options(),
) );

/* And then in the <input> name, use the array format. E.g.
<input name="my_fields[field_1]" value="<?php echo esc_attr(
    get_option( 'my_fields', my_fields_default_options() )['field_1']
); ?>">
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried option 2 (array method) and it worked perfectly

Comment: One question though, the first parameter of add_settings_field() can have a different id for each field, right?

Comment: Yes, of course it can :), and in fact, it should always be unique, just like the `id` attribute of an `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's a [reported issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15335) that is making our lives more difficult and has not been able to be fixed due to compatibility issues with existent themes and plugins.

In addition to Sally's answer, there is another option by using [`current_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_filter/) which is a workaround to not receiving the option's name as parameter.

```
add_action('admin_init','settings');


function settings(){
    add_settings_section('menu_first_section',null,null,'plugin-menu');

    add_settings_field('field_1','Field 1','field_1_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
    register_setting('option_group_1','field_1',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_general','default'=> ''));

    add_settings_field('field_2','Field 2','field_2_html','plugin-menu','menu_first_section');
    register_setting('option_group_2','field_2',array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_general','default'=> ''));
}

function sanitize_general($input) {

    // Strip the current option name from the filter name.
    $option = str_replace('sanitize_option_', '', current_filter());

    switch ( $option ) {
        case 'field_1':
            // TODO: sanitize $input as for field_1
            break;
        case 'field_2':
            // TODO: sanitize $input as for field_2
            break;
    }

    return $input;
}
```